# OPC UA Client server connection useing Open62541

Tags: c, opc-ua, open62541

I got a bit of an issue connecting a client on a Raspberry Pi to a server on a Raspberry pi and was hoping you guys had some ideas on how to resolve it.

Both of them have been setup using this guide
https://open62541.org/doc/current/building.html

and for simplicity I'm using the simple client and server setup from their site as well, found at

https://open62541.org/doc/current/tutorial_client_firststeps.html

and

https://open62541.org/doc/current/tutorial_server_firststeps.html

only difference being that since I'm using the UA_ENABLE_AMALGAMATION option the

```
#include <open62541/plugin/log_stdout.h>
#include <open62541/server.h>
#include <open62541/server_config_default.h>
```

have been changed out for

```
#include "open62541.h"
```

The readout I'm getting is

```
[2020-12-29 13:32:40.456 (UTC+0100)] warn/server        AccessControl: Unconfigured AccessControl. Users have all permissions.
[2020-12-29 13:32:40.456 (UTC+0100)] info/server        AccessControl: Anonymous login is enabled
[2020-12-29 13:32:40.456 (UTC+0100)] warn/server        Username/Password configured, but no encrypting SecurityPolicy. This can leak credentials on the network.
[2020-12-29 13:32:40.456 (UTC+0100)] warn/userland      AcceptAll Certificate Verification. Any remote certificate will be accepted.
[2020-12-29 13:32:40.458 (UTC+0100)] info/network       TCP network layer listening on opc.tcp://xx:4840/
```

for the server and

```
[2020-12-29 13:32:43.668 (UTC+0100)] warn/userland      AcceptAll Certificate Verification. Any remote certificate will be accepted.
[2020-12-29 13:32:43.671 (UTC+0100)] warn/network       Connection to opc.tcp://localhost:4840 failed with error: Connection refused
[2020-12-29 13:32:43.671 (UTC+0100)] info/client        Client Status: ChannelState: Closed, SessionState: Closed, ConnectStatus: BadDisconnect
```

for the client

I can connect to both of the raspberry's with UaExpert just fine but for some reason the client just does not want to connect?

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

These are the current configurations for Open62541 also

[image: Open62541 configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the basic client / server communications by plugin a ethernet cable into both of the raspberry's and connecting to the server on the wireless for some reason.

Think I there is some setting issue with one of them.